# Breaking DDH assumption

Tags: discrete-logarithm

DDH says that: $(g,g^a,g^b,g^c)$ should be indistinguishable from $(g,g^a,g^b,g^{ab})$ assuming $a,b,c\in Z_P$.

However, since $Z_p$ is finite and has $p-1$ elements, can we not just try $n^2$ combinations?

Comment: Well that's commonly called a brute force attack; under a proper definition of the assumption it does not constitute a break.

Answer (score 2):

Because p is huge.

The algorithm that generates all n^2 = (p-1)^2 combinations is exponential in the security parameter λ (=log p). The security definition is against all PPTs (Probabilistic Polynomial Time) adversaries.

Comment: why is (p-1)^2 exponential? it looks quadratic to me!

Comment: It is quadratic in p, but p is not the input of the algorithm.The security parameter is the input of the algorithm ie. the length of the key.For instance a key of length 1024 generated a group of size 2^1024 and there are 2^2048 combinations.